# When should you use popovers in an iPhone app?

Tags: mobile, iphone

I am working on an iPhone app for a client.

At the moment they have a main page for viewing a list of events and then a "filter" button to press to take you to another page to set the distancea away from the users current locations. The filters just affect that page.

I wondered if it would be appropriate to use popovers for this - just because they more directly link the page to the filters.

And that got me to thinking whether there is any **best practice for using popovers** in an iPhone app?

Oh yes and are they called popovers or popups? (:

Here is an example of a popover:

[image]

More here: http://mobile-patterns.com/popovers

Comment: Pop-up indicates a modal (or a different "window" in desktop situations), I'd definitely call that a pop-over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't come up with specific best practices, but I have seen a worst practice in use quite a bit: Using pop-overs when a separate page would make more sense.

In your example, I'd see that as a quick navigation tool, and probably makes sense to leave as a pop-over.

But I've also seen apps based off of existing desktop apps where they had made use of a lot of modals. On a mobile device, if you're using the modal to display content, the modal tends to have to be as big as the screen itself. As such, making it a modal doesn't really benefit the user and often is a detriment, as now you have to deal with scrolling/navigating around a modal. Often, the better option would be to use a new 'page'. I use 'page' in brackets in that it doesn't have to physically be a new web page if we're talking a web app--but it should be a full page in the sense that it's a native mobile screen. A common UI interaction would be to slide the current page to the left to show the 'modal' content sliding in from the right.

So...after typing that, maybe I did formulate a best practice:

> Don't use pop-overs on mobile to display page content. Consider expandable sections and/or separate 'pages'. Leave pop-overs for single task interactions such as navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an old question but aren't popover controls only available on iPads.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html

> Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices.
>   Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception

Comment: Clearly not as the examples above come from mobiles :-)

Comment: @LisaTweedie that example looks custom (if a real screenshot) or could just be an image mockup. either way you cant have popovers on an iPhone app only iPad - see link.